# Proof of $Z(I(X))=X$ for $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ a projective algebraic set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective algebraic set.

That $X \subset Z(I(X))$ is clear. For the other inclusion, let's take $x\in Z(I(X))$ and we want to see that $x\in X$. Since $x\in Z(I(X))$, then $f(x)=0$ for all homogeneous $f\in I(X)$. My question is, how does that necessarily imply that $x\in X$? We know that for homogeneous $f\in I(X)$, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$, but how do we know that there isn't a point $q\in \mathbb{P}^n \setminus X$ such that all homogeneous $f\in I(X)$ vanish at said point $q$?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that vanishing on a point in projective space does not make sense for arbitrary polynomials. I recall that you would usually consider homogenous plynomials and $I(X)$ would be the ideal generated by the homogenous polyomials vanishing on $X$ and $Z(I)$ would only be defined for homogeneous ideals. Furthermore, I believe the identity $Z(I(X)) = X$ should not be true for arbitrary $X$. In fact, $Z(I(X))$ should be the closure of $X$ with respect to the Zariski topology.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch You're indeed correct, I have edited the question. If I am not mistaken, a projective algebraic set is closed in the Zariski Topology, and then $X$ equals the closure of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ is any subset, then you only have the inclusion $X\subset Z(I(X))=\overline{X}$. However, in the question it is assumed that $X$ is an algebraic set so $X=Z(J)$ for some homogeneous ideal $J\subset I(X)$. Now if $p\in Z(I(X))-X$, then every polynomial in $I(X)$ vanishes on $p$ and hence $J$ also vanishes on $p$ contradicting the fact that $p\in Z(J)=X$.